# Liferay 6.2 w/ Angular 5: The selector "app-root" did not match any element

Tags: angular, liferay, angular5, liferay-6.2

I am currently trying bootstrap angular 5 inside a portlet. This portlet is the only portlet on the page. When I navigate to the page that contains the portlet I do not see any of the UI content that should be displayed. I get an error in the browser console stating **"Error" The selector "app-root" did not match any elements."** Below is my main configuration:

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/liferay-portlet.xml

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>businessmobileapp</portlet-name>
    <virtual-path>${admin.portlet.path}/toolsAdmin</virtual-path>
    <instanceable>false</instanceable>
    <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
    <ajaxable>true</ajaxable>

    <header-portlet-css>/lib/select2/select2.css</header-portlet-css>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/core-responsive.css</header-portlet-css>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/toggle.css</header-portlet-css>
    <header-portlet-css>/css/businessmobileapp/bma.css</header-portlet-css>

    <header-portlet-javascript>/tools-admin-migration-a5/dist/inline.bundle.js</header-portlet-javascript>
    <header-portlet-javascript>/tools-admin-migration-a5/dist/polyfills.bundle.js</header-portlet-javascript>
    <header-portlet-javascript>/tools-admin-migration-a5/dist/styles.bundle.js</header-portlet-javascript>
    <header-portlet-javascript>/tools-admin-migration-a5/dist/vendor.bundle.js</header-portlet-javascript>
    <header-portlet-javascript>/tools-admin-migration-a5/dist/main.bundle.js</header-portlet-javascript>
</portlet>
```

src/main/webapp/portlets/businessmobileapp/view.vm

```
<app-root></app-root>
```

tools-admin-migration-a5/main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

app/app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BusinessMobileAppComponent } from './business-mobile-app/business-mobile-app.component';
import { AppComponent} from "./app.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      BusinessMobileAppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }[/code]

app/app.component.ts
[code]import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

app/app.component.html

```
{{title}}
some title
<business-mobile-app></business-mobile-app>
```

the structure of my application is as follows:
**tools-portlet**
   ___|src
____|main
_____|webapp
________|tools-admin-migration-a5
___________|dist
___________|node_modules
___________|src
____________|app
_____________|business-mobile-app

P.S. I also tried do in include in the view.vm file to include the index.html file from the angular app to see if that would solve it but it didn't.

[image: Error]

EDIT: I forgot the index.html file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ToolsAdminMigrationA5</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you importing your view.vm under `head` tags? If so, try put it under `body`

Comment: No, i am using liferay to render the view.vm